# StringR str_detect removes 1 obs if negate = TRUE but keeps 0 observations if negate = FALSE

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I am cleaning a dataset and stumbled over the following:
I have a dataSet with 612 observations. I want to filter out every refurl that contains the phrase "admin". So I have the following code:

```
DataSet_Cleaned <- DataSet %>%
  filter(str_detect(refurl, "admin", negate = TRUE))
```

The DataSet_Cleaned now includes 611 observations.
I now want to know which observation was removed so I reverse it:

```
DataSet_Cleaned <- DataSet %>%
  filter(str_detect(refurl, "admin", negate = FALSE))
```

The new DataSet has 0 observations. So something seems to be fishy here.
Can anybody tell me what is happening? Manually looking for a an entry that includes "admin" yielded no result (which makes this problem not as pressing) but I am kind weary of what is happening here.

The same happens if I negate the query via !

```
DataSet_Cleaned <- DataSet %>%
  filter(!str_detect(refurl, "admin"))
```

Thank you!
-Jan

Comment: Can you provide an example using which we can verify what you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue:
One of the refurl values was N/A which was removed.